# Woocommerce attribute returns "attribute_pa_attribute_name"

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Here is the loop I go through to get the product attributes, I get the product and then its variations in the data it provides the the attributes in the array is attribute_pa_color, attribute_pa_size... I want to return just the name like "color" not "attribute_pa_color"

```
$product = wc_get_product( $id );
$available_variations = $product->get_available_variations();
foreach ($available_variations as $attribute_name=> $value) 
{ 
 // $attribute_name returns "attribute_pa_color" for example
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$product = wc_get_product( $id );
$available_variations = $product->get_available_variations();
foreach ($available_variations as $attribute_name=> $value) 
{ 
 echo $attribute_name=> $value->attribute_pa_color
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/32104386)

Comment: @AhmedurRahmanShovon Please pay attention when reviewing, this is not a comment. Although code-only answers are considered low-quality, they are still answers. That means you should select "Looks OK", and maybe downvote, even if the answer is completely wrong.

Comment: I want to add the label dynamically, so I wont know the attributes by name, I am just testing it and have added attributes, the only data I am receiving is the slug I cannot find the attribute name in the data